# What is the difference between a "Model" and a "Context" in Entity Framework jargon?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the difference between a "model" and a "context" in Entity Framework jargon?

I'm using the Entity Framework database first approach in an application. These terms have come up many times as I've been reading different forums and articles on EF implementation strategies. I can't seem to figure out how these two are different (not even with just entity framework, but with software development in general). People use the words as if they are different, but then some people seem to use the words interchangeably.

Comment: The `DbContext` class is the base class that allows for database querying used in EF. The model in the MVC sense can refer to the general domain that includes entities (also named models) and database connections or might refer to a model, in which they basically mean a class that is used to represent your data (for example `Person`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Context**

This is easy. The context is either the `DbContext` or the older `ObjectContext` class that is the core of the entity framework data access layer. It supplies transparent database access through strong typed sets of entities, tracks and saves changes, manages database transactions and connections, and contains a number of utility methods to facilitate all kinds of data access tasks (esp. `DbContext`).

**Model**

This can be two (or three) things.

- The data model, or store model. Which is the relational model of the database underlying the EF data access layer.
- The conceptual model, or class model. Which is the .Net class model that represents the database. This model can either be generated by EF (database-first) or it can be an existing class model (code first). The conceptual model and the store model are linked through *mapping*, so EF knows how to populate .Net classes from database records and, conversely, how to save .Net classes to the database.
- Some people refer to the classes in the conceptual model as "models". This is not wrong, but I prefer to use the name [entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16461807/861716) for this.

So *context* and *model* are two quite different things. You might say that the context is the middleman between two different types of models.

Comment: Considering bullet point #2 from your answer, what would be the reason why anyone would ever have more dbContexts than models and vice-versa? Is there a best practice when it comes to the number of models (edmx's) to the number of contexts used?

Comment: @user1431072 There can be reasons to have separate contexts each representing distinct parts of the database. For instance, if there are separate tables for authorization you could have an authorization context (with accompanying authorization class model) and a business context. More (store) models than context is not possible: a context accesses one database.

Answer (score 3):

Loosely speaking a context relates to a database connection or session wherea the model is the mapping between tables, views, etc to data access object classes (i.e., objects that will contain the data)

Answer (score 3):

A model is a class which usually represents a database table or structure to display a database table. For example, if I had a database for cars, then a model for car could be

```
public class Car
{
 [Key]
 public int CarId { get; set; }
 public string Make { get; set; }
 public string Model { get; set; }
 public int Year { get; set; } 
}
```

This model is used by entity framework and the sql provider (for mysql or mssql usually) to compose a query against a database. The query requires a way for this to be mapped, and that is the job of the context. The context usually extends `DbContext` and is what is used for the facade of accessing the database table as an in memory object.

```
public class CarContext : DbContext
{
 DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```